# Updating array in mongo db

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am having below data in my collection where I am trying to update an array.

```
{
  "DESCRIPTION": "Sample",
  "USERS": [
    {
      "USER_ID": "001",
      "USER_TYPE": "A",
      "USER_ACCOUNT": "ACCOUNTS"
    },
    {
      "USER_ID": "002",
      "USER_TYPE": "A",
      "USER_ACCOUNT": "ACCOUNTS"
    }
  ]
}
```

**First Case**
If I want to update USER_TYPE of USER_ID "001", how can do using mongo query. Below query I tried its always push a new entry in the USERS array.

```
db.test.update({"USERS": {"$elemMatch":{"USER_ID":"001"}}},{"$addToSet":{"USERS":{"USER_ID":"001","USER_TYPE":"B","USER_ACCOUNT":"ACCOUNTS"}}},{"upsert":true})
```

**Second case**
If new USER_ID is passed in UPDATE query, then new entry must be pushed to array.

Can someone help me what I am doing wrong in it.

Comment: Your 'collection data' is missing an _id. Are you showing the contents of a collection named USERS, one USERS document in the collection, or one sub-document in a document?

Comment: Its content of the test collection. With one USER array and other fields at root level

Comment: Let me restate for clarity: this is one document in a collection with _id and some fields omitted, showing only USERS to focus on the question. Is this right? Does every document have a USERS collection? Does every USER in every array in every document have a distinct USER_ID?

Comment: If not, is the collection full of something like application documents where the same user could could have configuration in several applications. Hope this doesn't seem nit-picky, but it affects how I would answer.

Comment: @SteveTarver Tarver i have updated my posy by adding the full data what exists in my collection

Comment: Let me try to clarify: If you have a single document you want to modify, you need a field that is unique to the document. If you want to modify every user in every document with a specific user id, you need a different query - which is it?